# Is there a way to split one big .sass file into multiple .css via Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I'm working on a multipage application, and I'm trying to make improvements on the bundle process. I already managed to upgrade to Webpack 5 and improve the dev experience, but the big issue that I simply cannot solve is that I cannot serve CSS per page, and not a gigantic CSS file, [see here the coverage on DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erU0T.png)

I have tried splitChunks, but I think that's not related. I also cannot use [html-critical-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-critical-webpack-plugin), or anything that needs changes on the DevOps/Back-End side (currently it does not work). I know it sounds like I didn't search correctly, but I tried a lot, from the docs to a Udemy course, but probably I'm focusing on the wrong problem. My webpack config for production is as follows:

```
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const paths = require('./paths.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
mode: 'production',

devtool: false,

output: {
  filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
  path: paths.build,
  publicPath: '/',
  assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
  clean: true
},

module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(s?css|sass)$/i,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 2,
            sourceMap: false,
            modules: false,
          },
        },
        'sass-loader',
      ],
    },
  ]
},

plugins: [
  new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
    minimizerOptions: {
      // Lossless optimization with custom option
      // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
      plugins: [
        ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
        ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
        // Svgo configuration here https://github.com/svg/svgo#configuration
        [
          'svgo',
          {
            plugins: [
              'preset-default',
              {
                name: 'removeViewBox',
                active: false,
              },
              {
                name: 'addAttributesToSVGElement',
                params: {
                  attributes: [{ xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' }],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  }),

  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css'
  }),

  new CompressionPlugin({
    algorithm: 'gzip',
    test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
  }),
],

optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), '...'],
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
  },
},

performance: {
  hints: false,
  maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
  maxAssetSize: 512000,
},
});
```

And the common:

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: [
      './src/scripts/components/slick-slider.js',
      './src/scripts/components/card-slider.js',
      './src/scripts/components/video.js',
      './src/scripts/components/nova-home.js',
      './src/scripts/components/accordion.js',
    ],
    shared: [
      './src/scripts/components/header-menu.js',
      './src/scripts/components/home.js',
      './src/scripts/util/modernizer-webpdetect',
      './src/scripts/components/slide-cards',
      './src/scripts/components/accordion',
      './src/scripts/components/top-banner',
      './src/scripts/components/appLinks'
    ],
    simule: [
      './src/scripts/components/simulate.js',
      './src/scripts/components/feed.js',
      './src/scripts/components/dropdown.js'
    ],
    ouvidoria: [
      './src/scripts/components/ouvidoria-form.js',
      './src/scripts/components/maks.js'
    ],
    tesouroDireto: [
      './src/scripts/components/simulate.js',
      './src/scripts/components/video.js',
      './src/scripts/components/dropdown.js'
    ],
    cbdELc: [
      './src/scripts/components/simulate.js',
      './src/scripts/components/video.js',
    ],
    coe: [
      './src/scripts/components/video.js'
    ],
    lciELca: [
      './src/scripts/components/simulate.js',
      './src/scripts/components/video.js'
    ],
    fundosDeIndices: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    fundosImobiliarios: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    investimentos: [
      './src/scripts/components/swipe-view.js',
    ],
    precos: [
      './src/scripts/components/feed.js',
      './src/scripts/components/precos.js'
    ],
    ofertasPublicas: [
      './src/scripts/components/public-offers.js'
    ],
    acoes: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    bdr: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    carteira: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    fundosInvestimentos: [
      './src/scripts/components/funds-list.js'
    ],
    comeceInvestir: [
      './src/scripts/components/comece-investir.js',
      './src/scripts/components/slick-slider.js',
      './src/scripts/components/card-slider.js',
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    bolsaValores: [
      './src/scripts/components/section-portfolio'
    ],
    comparadorFundos: [
      './src/comparadorFundos.js'
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              attrs: ['img:src', 'source:srcset']
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'pug-html-loader',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|webm|mp4|pdf)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline',
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: './src/img/*',
          to: './'
        },
        {
          from: './src/video/*',
          to: './'
        },
        {
          from: './src/sitemap.xml',
          to: './'
        },
        {
          from: './src/robots.txt',
          to: './'
        }
      ]
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.pug',
      filename: './index.html',
      chunks: ['index', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/sobre-nos.pug',
      filename: './sobre-nos.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/seguranca.pug',
      filename: './dicas-de-seguranca-para-investir.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/primeiros-passos.pug',
      filename: './investir-para-iniciantes.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/simule.pug',
      filename: './simulador-de-investimentos.html',
      chunks: ['simule', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/ouvidoria.pug',
      filename: './ouvidoria.html',
      chunks: ['ouvidoria', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/tributacao.pug',
      filename: './tributacao-de-renda-fixa.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-tesouro-direto.pug',
      filename: './investir-tesouro-direto.html',
      chunks: ['tesouroDireto', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-cdb-e-lc.pug',
      filename: './investir-cdb-e-lc.html',
      chunks: ['cbdELc', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-coe.pug',
      filename: './investir-coe.html',
      chunks: ['coe', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-cri-e-cra.pug',
      filename: './investir-cri-e-cra.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-debentures.pug',
      filename: './investir-debentures.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/pagina-404.pug',
      filename: './404.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-lci-e-lca.pug',
      filename: './investir-lci-e-lca.html',
      chunks: ['lciELca', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-titulos-publicos.pug',
      filename: './titulos-publicos.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-ofertas-publicas.pug',
      filename: './ofertas-publicas.html',
      chunks: ['ofertasPublicas', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-fundos-de-investimentos.pug',
      filename: './investir-fundos-de-investimentos.html',
      chunks: ['fundosInvestimentos', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-acoes.pug',
      filename: './investir-acoes.html',
      chunks: ['acoes', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/carteira-investimento-recomendada.pug',
      filename: './investir-carteira-recomendada.html',
      chunks: ['carteira', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/trader.pug',
      filename: './investir-trader.html',
      chunks: ['trader', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-fundos-de-indices.pug',
      filename: './investir-etf.html',
      chunks: ['fundosDeIndices', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/plataformas-trader.pug',
      filename: './plataformas-investir-trader.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-fundos-imobiliarios.pug',
      filename: './investir-fii-fundos-imobiliarios.html',
      chunks: ['fundosImobiliarios', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-mercado-de-opcoes.pug',
      filename: './investir-mercado-de-opcoes.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-mini-ibovespa.pug',
      filename: './investir-mini-indice.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-mini-dolar.pug',
      filename: './investir-mini-dolar.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/alavancagem-day-trade-bovespa.pug',
      filename: './investir-day-trade.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/bdr-investir-exterior.pug',
      filename: './investir-bdr.html',
      chunks: ['bdr', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-contrato-indice.pug',
      filename: './investir-contrato-indice-bovespa.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-fundos-de-indices.pug',
      filename: './produto-fundos-de-indices.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-contrato-dolar.pug',
      filename: './investir-contrato-dolar.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/renda-variavel.pug',
      filename: './investir-renda-variavel.html',
      chunks: ['rendaVariavel', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/mercado-futuro.pug',
      filename: './investir-mercado-futuro.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/produto-letra-financeira.pug',
      filename: './investir-letra-financeira.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/investimentos.pug',
      filename: './investimentos.html',
      chunks: ['investimentos', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/precos.pug',
      filename: './taxas-e-precos.html',
      chunks: ['precos', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/tributacao-variavel.pug',
      filename: './tributacao-de-renda-variavel.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/politica-de-privacidade.pug',
      filename: './politica-de-privacidade.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/termos-de-uso.pug',
      filename: './termos-de-uso.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/regulamentacao.pug',
      filename: './regulamentacao.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/nossos-resultados.pug',
      filename: './resultados.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/gestao-de-recursos.pug',
      filename: './gestao-de-recursos.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/comece-a-investir.pug',
      filename: './comecar-a-investir.html',
      chunks: ['comeceInvestir', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/bolsa-de-valores.pug',
      filename: './investir-bolsa-de-valores.html',
      chunks: ['bolsaValores', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/comparador-fundos.pug',
      filename: './investir-comparador-fundos.html',
      chunks: ['comparadorFundos', 'shared']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/politica-seguranca-informacao.pug',
      filename: './politica-de-seguranca-da-informacao.html',
      chunks: ['shared']
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/'),
      data: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/data/'),
      fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/fonts/'),
      img: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/img/'),
      scripts: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts/'),
      statics: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/statics/'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/'),
      video: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/video/')
    }
  }
}
```

The project has a lot of .sass files, to each component/page. These are imported into a main.sass, which is imported in the `home.js`, in the shared entry point. I suspect this is the problem, but maybe someone could help me?